# Selenium using Xpath on IE8 vs Firefox3.6

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, selenium, selenium-rc, xpath

Is there any discernible reason as to why Selenium finds and successfully executes the following command on a Firefox browser, but not IE8 (via selenium RC)

```
selenium.click("//input[@type='Radio' 
                        and starts-with(@name, 'client-select') 
                        and @value='0']");
```

Im assuming its something to do with IE "rendering" (not sure the correct term) xpath differently to firefox.  Is this the case? How do they differ?  What articles do you know that will help me overcome this and similar issues regarding the two browsers and xpath?

Much thanks.

**EDIT**

The element in question is:

```
<input type="Radio" 
       value="1" 
       onfocus="" 
       onclick="return doRTgl(this);" 
       onblur="" 
       name="client-select_1580158">
```

Its nested within some pretty messed up nested tables, and is added dynamically via Ajax.

Comment: Well in your XPath you have `@value='0'`, yet for the input you have `value="1"` so that path does not apply to the input. Other potential problems (I don't know Selenium) when you do XPath over HTML are the case of element names and attribute names and values, try whether using `@type='radio'` works better.

Comment: Good pickup.  I actually just used a bad example.  Radio's with both >>@value=0 and >>@value=1 are present. Sorry. Will try the different case for type.

Comment: Changing @type='Radio' to @type='radio' did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: Stupidly enough though, an xpath with @type='radio' will not work in FFox.  It has to be @type='Radio'.  Grrrr.  Im going to have to implement two different xpaths depending on testing environment to compensate for two competing browsers incapability of agreeing on such a simple matter of capitalisation of element attributes.

Comment: You could use all this information to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove the type from the xpath locator

```
 selenium.click("//input[starts-with(@name, 'client-select') 
                    and @value='0']");
```

Which fortunately left me with enough information to find the unique element each time.

As far as the generic question, an xpath that works on Firefox won't necessarily work on IE.  This was the only case however I found during refactoring of my code. For future reference, just have to test on each, find the differences and work around.